# inserting ô into mysql database is part of Rhône results in Rh

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

When I insert the string 'Rhône' into my database, all that remains is 'Rh'
How is that possible?
Is use Mysql with utf8_general_ci encoding.

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>Decode</title>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/v3/functions/connect.php');

$res_id = $_POST['res_id'];
$yr_id = $_POST['yr_id'];

$yr_id=html_entity_decode($yr_id, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");


 if(isset($yr_id) && $yr_id<>'') {

$search  = array('%C3%B4');
$replace = array('ô');
$yr_id=str_replace($search, $replace, $yr_id);



 mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
   $uQuery2="UPDATE sv_snowrepublic set yr_id='$yr_id' where res_id=$res_id limit 1";
  $uResult2  = mysql_query($uQuery2);
  echo 'updated';

  } 







  $uQuery1="SELECT * FROM sv_snowrepublic where res_id=$res_id limit 1";
  $uResult1  = mysql_query($uQuery1);
  $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($uResult1);


if (mysql_num_rows($uResult1) >= 1 && isset($res_id) && $res_id>2)

     {
echo "<form method='POST' action='index.php'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' size='4' value='" . $row1['res_id'] . "' name='res_id'  /><br />";

$yr2_id=$row1['yr_id'];
// $yr2_id=html_entity_encode($yr2_id, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
echo mb_detect_encoding($yr2_id);

echo "<input type='text' size='200' value='" . $yr2_id . "' name='yr_id'  /><br />";
echo "<br /><label for='submit'></label><input  type='submit' name='submit' value=' Send '></form>";
        }       


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is that possible?

You have got a problem to transfering the string `Rhône` into your MySQL database. This can have multiple reasons, most certainly one of the components involved (most certainly MySQL as server or client) runs over a string with an encoding specified which does not match at the character position you commonly refer to as `ô`. As it's the first position the encoding looks invalid, it will get cut off.

You must ensure, under all circumstance and without making any error - not even the slightest one in configuration - that the encoding of the data you handle is always clear to you, correctly set-up and properly handled.

That's both for the input into your database as well as for getting the data from your database.

The thing that comes to mind is:

- You don't save your php file encoded as UTF-8 to disc.

Further on:

- You're not using the recommended MySQL client extension.
- You're using `SET NAMES` instead of setting up the connection encoding settings properly. See [`mysql_set_charset`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php).

Check that, but it's only a guess, there can be many reasons why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

you should set connection encoding to `UTF-8` too. Try

```
SET NAMES UTF-8
```

after connection, before first query

Comment: Better use [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) instead of `SET NAMES`.

Comment: Better don't use mysql_* extension:)

Comment: Well, OP is using them, but I have a [Long version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975451/inserting-o-into-mysql-database-is-part-of-rhone-results-in-rh/6975803#6975803) as well, see *Further on:*.

Comment: @hakre: you win(convince me) today :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql_* functions, you need to make sure you escape the string with mysql_real_escape_string(), however it is recommended to use prepared statements using PDO or mysqli.

Comment: definitely very good advice, though I'm not sure it's directly answering the question.

Comment: It might be. Try escaping your strings and see if that makes any difference. It will also prevent SQL injection, which you are vulnerable to. Have you tried without the `SET NAMES utf8` query? I've never had any problems just inputting UTF-8 characters into the DB before without having to set any character encodings.